# Why can't Pandas read my CSV?

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

path = r'‪C:\Users\matt\Documents\sample.csv'
sample = pd.read_csv(path)

print sample
```

> IOError: File â€ªC:\Users\matt\Documents\sample.csv does not exist

I tried:

```
r'‪C:/Users/matt/Documents/sample.csv'
'‪C:/Users/matt/Documents/sample.csv'
'C:\\Users\\matt\\Documents\\sample.csv'
```

All yield the sameresult.

[image: Proof that the file exists.]

Comment: os.path.exists(path) is returning false!

Comment: what does `print(path)` say?

Comment: path = r'‪C:\Users\matt\Documents\sample.csv'; print path; says C:\Users\matt\Documents\sample.csv

Comment: How about `print(repr(path))`? The error message you show has some "garbage" characters before the `C:` bit. Perhaps you have a non-visible character in your string?

Comment: Try `sample = pd.read_csv(r'‪C:/Users/matt/Documents/sample.csv')`

Comment: says '\xe2\x80\xaaC:\\Users\\matt\\Documents\\sample.csv'

Comment: so there something in your `path` variable before `C:` as @Blckknght said

Comment: sample = pd.read_csv(r'‪C:/Users/matt/Documents/sample.csv') gives same result

Comment: make sure that you are using correct single quotes - don't copy and paste them type them, same with `C` - make sure it's a latin character `C`

Comment: typing it working @MaxU! Not sure how that makes a difference. I'm on Win10 Home 64 Bit using 32 Bit iPython Notebook with Python 2.7. I copied the file path from the securities tab of the document properties.

Comment: I guess it's a beautified (unicode) version of single quote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trash before my C was the problem.

> â€ª

This trash came from the copy paste I did to put in the path.

Hand typing in the file path solved the problem.